# Did Quran introduce any new words to the Arabic?

Tags: quran, arabic

At the time of its revelation, did Quran introduce any new words to the Arabic language? I.e., were there unique words in the Quran which Arabs heard for the first time through Quran? If yes, do we know what these words are?

Comment: There are words that no one knows the meaning of ... these can be classified as muqaṭṭaʿāt... such words would include but not be limited to Alif Lām Mīm, ʾAlif Lām Mīm Ṣād, Kāf Hā Yā ʿAin Ṣād , Ṭā Sīn Mīm, Yā Sīn, Ḥā Mīm etc

Comment: What would be the benefit? I mean the qur'an and sunnah tell us that is important to address the people in the manner/language they know!

Comment: @Medi1Saif It could first introduce the word and then explain the meaning. Further, doesn’t Qur’an itself says it contains some verses whose meanings are less than explicit?

Comment: The qur'an rather has an influence on the language and its spreading, but didn't really introduce new words.

Comment: @Medi1Saif If you add some sources to that claim, I’d be happy to accept it as an answer:)